# Custom Upload Directory for Wordpress Media Uploader in own Plugin

Tags: php, file-upload, wordpress

I´am currently work on a Wordpress Plugin and I like to set a custom upload directory for the wordpress media uploader, which I use on one subpage of my plugin. I have searched a whole week but I can´t find my mistake or a solution for my problem - so I hope anyone could help.

I add a submenu page where I call a method to load the WP Media Uploader:

```
add_submenu_page('w3p-listing', $pubAtt, $pubAtt, 'manage_options', 'w3p-attachments', array('w3pUploader', 'media_upload_init') );
```

This call the media_upload_init Method on the class w3pUploader which looks like that:

```
class w3pUploader {

function __construct()
{

}

public static function media_upload_init() {
    // jQuery
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    // This will enqueue the Media Uploader script
    wp_enqueue_media();
    ?>

    <div>
        <label for="image_url">Image</label>
        <input type="text" name="image_url" id="image_url" class="regular-text">
        <input type="button" name="upload-btn" id="upload-btn" class="button-secondary" value="Upload Image">
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('#upload-btn').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var image = wp.media({
                    title: 'Upload Image',
                    // mutiple: true if you want to upload multiple files at once
                    multiple: false
                }).open()
                .on('select', function(e){
                    // This will return the selected image from the Media Uploader, the result is an object
                    var uploaded_image = image.state().get('selection').first();
                    // We convert uploaded_image to a JSON object to make accessing it easier
                    // Output to the console uploaded_image
                    console.log(uploaded_image);
                    var image_url = uploaded_image.toJSON().url;
                    // Let's assign the url value to the input field
                    $('#image_url').val(image_url);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}

function awesome_wallpaper_dir( $param ){
    $mydir = '/awesome';

    $param['path'] = $param['path'] . $mydir;
    $param['url'] = $param['url'] . $mydir; 

    return $param;
}

}
```

I found several topics about that but not one solve my issue:

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/upload_dir
- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76895/different-upload-directory-based-on-post-type-in-a-theme/77007#77007
- https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/83248/post-type-specific-upload-folder-in-3-5/83254#83254

I tried to add the filter before the wp_enque_media() function, in my activation class and also in my plugin constructor but the upload dir hook was not recognized or gave me errors like: "Error on uploading media ..."
I used that line:

```
add_filter( 'upload_dir', array('w3pUploader', 'customize_upload_dir' ));
```

I hope anyone has a idea where I am wrong or how to solve that problem.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it in a bit different way but it works:

I added those 3 lines after the enqueue_media() function in the w3pUploader class:

```
update_option('upload_path',WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/uploads/CUSTOM_FOLDER');
update_option('upload_url_path','../wp-content/uploads/CUSTOM_FOLDER');
update_option('uploads_use_yearmonth_folders', false);
```

The three update option calls set the new upload dir global when the media uploader is opened on my special page.

Then I updated the Javascript part with a close hook, so when the media uploader is closed in any way it got triggered:

```
on('close',function() {
    var data = {
        action: 'reset_upload_dir'
    };
    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });
});
```

The reset_upload_dir is a custom ajax function with I subscribed in my plugin main file in the constructor via:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_reset_upload_dir', array('w3pUploader', 'reset_upload_dir' ));
```

As the last step I added the reset_upload_dir function in my w3pUploader class:

```
public static function reset_upload_dir() {
    update_option('upload_path',null);
    update_option('upload_url_path',null);
    update_option('uploads_use_yearmonth_folders', true);
    echo "RETURN";
    wp_die();
}
```

This reset_upload_dir function set the options to null, which indicated wordpress to use its standards directory.

So the whole w3pUploader.php looks like that:

```
class w3pUploader {

function __construct()
{

}

public static function reset_upload_dir() {
    update_option('upload_path',null);
    update_option('upload_url_path',null);
    update_option('uploads_use_yearmonth_folders', true);
    echo "RETURN";
    wp_die();
}

public static function media_upload_init() {
    // jQuery
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    // This will enqueue the Media Uploader script
    wp_enqueue_media();

    update_option('upload_path',WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/uploads/w3p_publications');
    update_option('upload_url_path','../wp-content/uploads/w3p_publications');
    update_option('uploads_use_yearmonth_folders', false);
    ?>

    <div>
        <label for="image_url">Image</label>
        <input type="text" name="image_url" id="image_url" class="regular-text">
        <input type="button" name="upload-btn" id="upload-btn" class="button-secondary" value="Upload Image">
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('#upload-btn').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var image = wp.media({
                    title: 'Upload Image',
                    // mutiple: true if you want to upload multiple files at once
                    multiple: false
                }).open()
                .on('select', function(e){
                    // This will return the selected image from the Media Uploader, the result is an object
                    var uploaded_image = image.state().get('selection').first();
                    // We convert uploaded_image to a JSON object to make accessing it easier
                    // Output to the console uploaded_image
                    console.log(uploaded_image);
                    var image_url = uploaded_image.toJSON().url;
                    // Let's assign the url value to the input field
                    $('#image_url').val(image_url);
                }).on('close',function() {
                    var data = {
                        action: 'reset_upload_dir'
                    };
                    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                        alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
}
```

Comment: I am wondering what would happen if the media uploader is not closed for some reason, or if it remains open while another user is trying to upload content..  playing with global variables is dangerous